# How to Query AWS Service Status and publish a CURL command programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, statuspage-api

Is there anyway to Query AWS Service Status e.g.  if Kinesis Stream is Up or not, or S3 Storage Service is available or not ?  And on the basis of status, I want to execute certain CURL commands ?

I am looking to get a status for below services and then use it in our custom StatusPage

S3
API Gwy
Kinesis
SQS
Route53 + Cloudfront

I know there is statuspage for AWS Services but not sure how to use it programmatically and publish a CURL command.

Answer (score 0):

The [Service Health Dashboard](https://status.aws.amazon.com/) is usually delayed and not very useful for real-time monitoring of AWS health status.

Instead, you could use [AWS Health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/cloudwatch-events-health.html) from your account, which provides much more up-to-date events. What's more you can setup automated notifications and response to any issues detected as described in:

- [Monitoring AWS Health events with Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/cloudwatch-events-health.html)